# Angular-Devise not working properly with UserSerializer (Active Model Serializer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, active-model-serializers

I am using the [angular-devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise) Service in AngularJS to communicate with the Devise Authentication Gem in Rails. Everything (Login/Registration/Current_user/Facebook..) worked fine until I had to add this UserSerializer in Rails (Generated by Active Model Serializer Gem):

**serializers/user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :username, :provider, :uid, :name, :photo

  has_many :articles
end
```

Login, Registration and Oauth Login strangely still work like before. But I can't access the current user anymore in AngularJS with this function:

```
  Auth.currentUser().then(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });
```

Previously I could easily show the currentUser's username inside the view with  `{{user.username}}`

When I remove the user_serializer.rb file from Rails, I can access the currenUser in AngularJS again; but this doesn't solve my problem as I still need to output the has_many :articles associations in the user profile...

**Are there any known incompability issues between ASM and Devise Gem? 
How can I make this work?**

There are no Error messages, Angular just cant access the currentUser anymore, as soon as UserSerializer is present.

**EDIT1:**

JSON Output with UserSerializer disabled:

```
{"id":1,"email":"email@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-28T18:21:56.944Z","updated_at":"2015-10-31T14:06:25.846Z","username":"MuteMinute","provider":"facebook","uid":"1***5","name":"Alessandro Santamaria","photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1***5/picture"}
```

JSON Output with UserSerializer enabled (includes the auction model):

```
{"id":2,"email":"simon@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-30T12:31:25.480Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T12:31:25.488Z","username":"simon","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":null,"photo":null,"auctions":[{"id":6,"product":"Ridge Mini Cruiser Penny Skateboard","condition":"Wurde nur ca. 10 mal gefahren, das PennyBoard ist aus Hartplastik uns sehr stabil.","user":{"id":2,"email":"simon@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-30T12:31:25.480Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T12:31:25.488Z","username":"simon","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":null,"photo":null},"created_at":"2015-10-30T12:33:21.295Z","questions":[{"id":18,"body":"Have you driven that skateboard on rainy days?","auction_id":6,"created_at":"2015-10-30T23:38:59.777Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:29.219Z","user_id":1,"answer":"Never!","user":{"id":1,"email":"email@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-28T18:21:56.944Z","updated_at":"2015-10-31T14:06:25.846Z","username":"MuteMinute","provider":"facebook","uid":"1***5","name":"Alessandro Santamaria","photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1***5/picture"}},{"id":19,"body":"How much would shipping to UK be?","auction_id":6,"created_at":"2015-10-30T23:39:46.928Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:37.550Z","user_id":1,"answer":"20 Euro","user":{"id":1,"email":"email@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-28T18:21:56.944Z","updated_at":"2015-10-31T14:06:25.846Z","username":"MuteMinute","provider":"facebook","uid":"1***5","name":"Alessandro Santamaria","photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1***5/picture"}}],"bids":[{"id":20,"amount":5,"auction_id":6,"created_at":"2015-10-30T12:52:27.462Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T12:52:27.462Z","user_id":11,"user":{"id":11,"email":"thompson@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-30T12:51:19.082Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T12:51:19.086Z","username":"thompSon","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":null,"photo":null}},{"id":47,"amount":6,"auction_id":6,"created_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:46.394Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:46.394Z","user_id":1,"user":{"id":1,"email":"email@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-28T18:21:56.944Z","updated_at":"2015-10-31T14:06:25.846Z","username":"MuteMinute","provider":"facebook","uid":"1***5","name":"Alessandro Santamaria","photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1***5/picture"}},{"id":48,"amount":7,"auction_id":6,"created_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:50.235Z","updated_at":"2015-10-30T23:40:50.235Z","user_id":1,"user":{"id":1,"email":"email@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-10-28T18:21:56.944Z","updated_at":"2015-10-31T14:06:25.846Z","username":"MuteMinute","provider":"facebook","uid":"1***5","name":"Alessandro Santamaria","photo":"http://graph.facebook.com/1***5/picture"}}]}]}
```

AngularJS Controller for Auth (navCtrl):

```
  $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;

  $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

  Auth.currentUser().then(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });

  $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function (e, user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });

  $scope.$on('devise:login', function (e, user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });

  $scope. $on('devise:logout', function (e, user){
    $scope.user = {};
  });
```

Comment: Could you give: 1) an example of the output JSON when using the `UserSerializer`, and 2) the definition of your `Auth` factory?

Comment: Updated my question, I am not quite sure what you mean by your 2nd point, but I included the Controller. The `Auth` module is provided by angular-devise.

Comment: The fact that `provider` and `uid` are `null` when using AMS tells me there might be something wrong with your serializer. Are those actual attributes of your model?

Comment: this is just because of oauth, the user in this case has not connected his account with facebook, and signed up only with email. In the JSON example where UserSerializer is enabled, the User did connect his account with facebook.